# Server not receiving lists inside of JSON object passed in

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

These are the data contracts that are being used in the function.

```
public class ResumeSkillsListDataContract : IResumeSkillsListDataContract
{
    public IList<ISkillDataContract> KnownSkillsList { get; set; }
    public IList<ISkillDataContract> BadSkillsList { get; set; }
    public IList<ISkillDataContract> NewSkillsList { get; set; }
    public Int32 PersonId { get; set; } 
}

public class SkillDataContract : ISkillDataContract
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Int32> Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Boolean> IsAssigned { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Int32> SkillCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Int32> SkillCategoryMappingId { get; set; }
}
```

This is the function in the controller. I am expecting three populated lists and a PersonId to be passed in. However, I am only receiving the PersonId. In my Post, I see the data I am expecting to see in the console but when debugging the controller, *item*.List is empty every time.

```
  public IList<ISkillDataContract>      PostResumePersonSkills(ResumeSkillsListDataContract item)
        {
            var newList = item.KnownSkillsList;
            var ignoreList = item.BadSkillsList;
            var existingList = item.NewSkillsList;
            var personId = item.PersonId;


           return resumePersonSkillsBusinessLibrary.PostSkills(newList,      ignoreList, existingList, personId);
        }
```

Here is a quick snapshot of what im sending to the server. Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks.

```
    $scope.doneWithSkills = function () {
        var resumeCollection = {
            KnownSkillsList: $scope.KnownSkillsList, BadSkillsList: $scope.IgnoredSkillsList,
            NewSkillsList: $scope.SaveAsSkillsList, PersonId:$scope.ParsedPerson.Person.PersonId

        };
        resumeParserService.PostResumeSkills(resumeCollection);
    };
```

Function in the resumeParserService

```
self.PostResumeSkills = function (skills) {
    var url = 'ResumeSkill/PostResumePersonSkills';
    console.log(skills);
    webApiService.Post(url, skills);
};
```

Sample JSON being passed.

{"KnownSkillsList":[{"Name":"C++","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":154},{"Name":"Unix","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":219},{"Name":".Net","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":139},{"Name":"Clearcase","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":155},{"Name":"Uml","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":218},{"Name":"Xml","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":239},{"Name":"Java","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":173},{"Name":"Python","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":199},{"Name":"Visual Basic","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":223}],"BadSkillsList":[],"NewSkillsList":[{"Name":"Algorithms","Id":null,"IsAssigned":null,"SkillCategoryId":3,"SkillCategoryMappingId":null}],"PersonId":1203}

Comment: Have you looked at the JSON going over the wire? That would be the first thing to check - then you can see if it's a client issue or a server issue.

Comment: Yeah, I have. From what I can tell its clean. I'll add a clip of it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this is caused by your lists `ResumeSkillsListDataContract` being lists of an interface. The problem is going to be that when the JSON is deserialized the deserializer does not know what concrete type to instantiate.

Try changing to this and see if it resolves the problem

```
public class ResumeSkillsListDataContract : IResumeSkillsListDataContract
{
    public IList<SkillDataContract> KnownSkillsList { get; set; }
    public IList<SkillDataContract> BadSkillsList { get; set; }
    public IList<SkillDataContract> NewSkillsList { get; set; }
    public Int32 PersonId { get; set; } 
}
```